# Pandas concationation issue when reading data from Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[result of combining both dataframes...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8u1k.jpg)

I have two dataframes. One is converted from an API and the other is made from Excel data. Both dataframeshave the same amount of columns with the same name. When I try to concatenate the results of both dataframs and remove the duplicates, I still get both full dataframes. It seems that the formatting of the data that have been extracted from Excel has changed. How could I overcome this problem?

```
API_dictionary = dictionary['result']['list']

df = pd.DataFrame(API_dictionary)

if not my_file.is_file():  # file does not exists, create new one
    df.to_excel("list_of_items_in_dict.xlsx")

else:  # open excel file to add new items into excel file
    excel_df = pd.read_excel("list_of_items_in_dict.xlsx") 
    excel_df = excel_df[excel_df.columns[1:]] #remove first column that is created while exporting to excel

    frames = [df, excel_df]
    result = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
    result.to_excel("list_of_items_in_dict.xlsx") # make a new file with the added items from API dict

    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(result)

print("done")`
```

I expect a new Excel-file containing unique records of both dataframes.

Comment: It looks like `df` and `excel_df` have columns with values of different types (float, string) so you need to convert to the same type before calling `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

From screen you attachated, it seems as iun your Excel, float data is separated with comma and data from api is separated by dot. Pandas have problem with reading commas as float type and places you excel numbers as strings.

Try to change all commas do dots with:

```
excel_df = excel_df.str.replace(',', '.')
```

Problem should be gone then, always remember that you can use df.info() method to look what data type is in specific column (sometimes you can get only one row as a  string, and there you will find that information)